# Under replicated keys in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

Can anyone tell me how to check the under replicated keys in cassandra?

I know how to check the replication factor for the keyspace and "nodetool repair" for repairing but I was unable to find which of my keys are under replicated in my cluster.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra doesn't provide a way to know which keys may have had writes which didn't quite make it to all of the replicas. Even when repair is run it doesn't really provide to the other replicas which exact keys need to be repaired, but ranges where there are inconsistencies.

If you're wondering when to run repair: run it every week (if you have a default gc_grace of 10 days), or after an event where a node is down for more than an hour (or longer than the hint window).

Comment: I had a cluster with 1 replication initial but I changed it to 3 replication and ran the nodetool repair. So,how to confirm that the data is 3 times replicated and I could not find it through size of the data because we keep on adding the data every day after I changed it to 3 replication.

Comment: Now that RF is 3 data will be replicated on insert. Any under-replicated data was fixed when you ran repair. Keep running scheduled repairs, and that plus hinted handoff will keep your nodes consistent.